# URL and folder path different

Tags: php, wamp

I have a website wrote in PHP and running with WAMP server.

I am wondering if it's possible to access a file using a different URL of than original path??

Actually I have a file in `X:/wamp/www/test/test2/index.php` and I use `localhost/test/test/index.php` to access it. But can I create an alias or something to use `localhost/index.php` ?

Comment: I think you should do with virtual host apache. Try this http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is via Apache's excellent `ModRewrite`.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html